# Spring boot 6 + Angular CSRF throws 401 error, invalid csrf token

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cookies, spring-security, csrf

**Spring security**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(c -> c.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                        .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler())
                        .ignoringRequestMatchers("api/login", "api/register"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(a -> a
                        .requestMatchers("api/customers").hasRole("sample")
                        .requestMatchers("api/login", "api/register").permitAll())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200"); // Add this line to allow any origin
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("GET"); // Add this line to allow any method
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("POST"); // Add this line to allow any method
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*"); // Add this line to allow any headers
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```
public class CsrfCustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());

        System.out.println(csrfToken);
        System.out.println(csrfToken.getHeaderName());
        if (csrfToken.getHeaderName() != null) {
            response.setHeader(csrfToken.getHeaderName(), csrfToken.getToken());
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
...
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/service/auth.service';
import { getCookie } from 'typescript-cookie';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnDestroy {
  message = "no"
  subs = new Subscription()

  validateForm: FormGroup<{
    username: FormControl<string>;
    password: FormControl<string>;
    remember: FormControl<boolean>;
  }> = this.fb.group({
    username: ['', [Validators.required]],
    password: ['', [Validators.required]],
    remember: [true],
  });
  constructor(private fb: NonNullableFormBuilder, private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

  submitForm(): void {
    const userName = this.validateForm.get('username')?.value;
    const password = this.validateForm.get('password')?.value;

    localStorage.setItem('username', userName == undefined ? '' : userName);
    localStorage.setItem('password', password == undefined ? '' : password);

    this.subs = this.authService.basicAuthTestLogin().subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(getCookie("XSRF-TOKEN"))
    })
  }

  post() {
    this.authService.basiccsrfTest().subscribe((r) => {
      this.message = r.body || "";
      console.log(r.headers)
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subs.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public basiccsrfTest = () => {
    return this.httpClient
      .post('http://localhost:8080/api/customers', null, {
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'text'
      });
  };

  public basicAuthTestLogin = () => {
    return this.httpClient
      .post('http://localhost:8080/api/login', null, {
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'text',
        withCredentials:true
      });
  };
}
```

**auth-interceptor.service.ts**

```
...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor
  ) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

    const cookieheaderName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
    let csrfToken = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;

    const user = localStorage.getItem('username');
    const pass = localStorage.getItem('password');
    const csrf = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');

    let headers = {};
    if (user != undefined && pass != undefined) {
      headers = {
        ...headers,
        Authorization: `Basic ${window.btoa(user + ':' + pass)}`,
      };

      if (csrfToken !== null && !req.headers.has(cookieheaderName)) {
        headers = { ...headers, 'X-XSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken };
      }

      const authReq = req.clone({setHeaders:headers});
      return next.handle(authReq);
    }

    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
      cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      headerName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    }),
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: NZ_I18N, useValue: en_US },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptorService,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Sorry about so messed up codes,, i am just in the middle of learning spring security,,,
When I send post request to /api/login without csrf. The response is 200 and csrf cookie is also retrieved (I can see with the console.log()). And then, I make another post request /api/customers with the csrf token from /api/login response and basic auth (username and password). The response is 401,,,

When I checked the spring boot logs, it said that it is invalid csrf token,,, Does anyone know why it is invalid csrf token,,,??? and how to solve it?

**Expected Output**:

- Get csrf token from response header cookie (POST/api/login)
- then successfully send request (POST/api/customers) with the csrf token from the previous request

**Actual Output**:

- Get csrf token from response header cookie (POST/api/login) OK
- Get fail request (POST/api/customers) with the csrf token from the previous request. Invalid CSRF token (server-side log)

Comment: I solved it... it should include         withCredentials:true